# Access - Excel List Export replace Values

Tags: vba, excel, export, report

I have an Excel Report, there are values in Access which only have TRUE/FALSE Answers. How can I change these values each report to (for example) Open/Closed.

For this report I have got a query (excel_open_projects) which gets all the value I need.

```
Path = CurrentProject.Path & "\"
filename = "Open_Projects_" & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDDHHNNSS") & ".xls"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel2003, "excel_open_projects", Path & filename
```

I have already got a code which changes the Values in the first row:

```
Public Sub openXL()
'Variables to refer to Excel Objects
Dim MySheetPath As String
Dim Xl As Excel.Application
Dim XlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim XlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim row_count, i As Integer

' Tell it location of actual Excel file
MySheetPath = Path & filename
MsgBox MySheetPath

'Open Excel and the workbook
Set Xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set XlBook = GetObject(MySheetPath)

'Make sure excel is visible on the screen
Xl.Visible = True
XlBook.Windows(1).Visible = True

'Define the sheet in the Workbook as XlSheet
Set XlSheet = XlBook.Worksheets(1)

'Insert Row and the Value in the excel sheet starting at specified cell
XlSheet.Range("A1") = "Column A"

'Clean up and close worksheet
XlBook.Save
XlBook.Close

Set Xl = Nothing
Set XlBook = Nothing
Set XlSheet = Nothing

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the Problem:

```
For i = 1 To row_count
If XlSheet.Range("Y" & i) = "True" Then
XlSheet.Range("Y" & i) = "Yes"
ElseIf XlSheet.Range("Y" & i) = "False" Then
XlSheet.Range("Y" & i) = "No"
End If
Next
```